# can't use _strdate in Xcode (c++)

Tags: c++, xcode

I want to show current date and time in my c++ program. I did this simply by these lines of code:

```
char date[9], time[9];

_strdate( date );
_strtime( time );

cout << "Current date and time: " << date << " " << time << endl;
```

This perfectly worked in MS Visual C++ 2010 and Dev C++ 4.9.9.2. But this doesn't work in Xcode! It says that I'm using undeclared identifiers 'strdate' and 'strtime'. I have included *iostream* and *ctime* libraries, but this didn't help. What's the problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's no reason this should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
std::string _strdate_alternative()
{
 char cptime[50];
 time_t now = time(NULL);
 strftime(cptime, 50, "%b. %d, %Y", localtime(&now)); //short month name
 return std::string(cptime);
}
```

As said before, there is no such function in standard c/c++ library.
You can use this alternative. Code is based on some info found on the Internet. I didn't compile it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this displays the date perfectly and for displaying the time I did this:

    time_t rawtime;
    struct tm * timeinfo;
    char current_time [80];

    time (&rawtime);
    timeinfo = localtime (&rawtime);

    strftime (current_time,80,"%H:%M",timeinfo);

Answer (score 1):

These functions are not part of standard C++; they are Microsoft-specific extensions, and thus may not be available everywhere.

For similar functionality, you may try combining `time`, `localtime` and `strftime`.

Answer (score 0):

The function you are looking for is [`strftime`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/strftime.3.html).